# Coordinates of vertices of an icosahedron sitting on a face

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

I want to 3D print a wireframe of a icosahedron. For that I need the coordinates of the vertices so that one triangle lies flat on the $z=0$ plane.

All I've found are descriptions for an icosahedron standing on one vertice or and edge but not a face.

Does anyone have those coordinates?

Comment: First: The icosahedron in that set seems to be rather randomly oriented. It's not lieing on a face, nor standing on a vetrice. It's not even standing on an edge.

Comment: Secondly: "*PRIVATE* This information should not be disclosed to unauthorized persons. It is meant solely for use by authorized Bell System employees. *BELL LABORATORIES PROPRIETARY* Not for use or disclosure outside Bell Laboratories except by written approval of the director of the distributing organization. *BELL LABORATORIES RESTRICTED* The information herein is meant solely for use by authorized Bell Laboratories employees and is not to be disclosed to others. *NOTICE* Not for use or disclosure outside the Bell System except under written agreement." Did you read the manpage? Seriously?

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_icosahedron) gives us the coordinates $(0,\pm1,\pm\phi)$, $(\pm\phi,0,\pm1)$, $(\pm1,\pm\phi,0)$, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

To move a face to the bottom, just move the center of a face to the bottom. This can be done with a reflection. One of the faces is formed by the points $(0,1,-\phi),(0,-1,-\phi),(\phi,0,-1)$, so the direction of the center of the face is given by the vector $\vec a=(\phi,0,-1-2\phi)$, whose norm is $\sqrt{\phi^2+(1+2\phi)^2}=\sqrt{6+9\phi}$. To map the vector $\vec a$ to the vector $\vec b=(0,0,-\sqrt{6+9\phi})$, apply a reflexion through the hyperplane orthogonal to $\vec a-\vec b$. With the unit vector $\vec u=\dfrac{\vec a-\vec b}{||\vec a-\vec b||}$, the matrix of the transformation is $A=I-2uu^T$.

Then apply this matrix to all your points (seen as vectors starting at the origin).

I didn't try to simplify the result, so here are numerical coordinates ($x,y,z$ on each line, ordered by increasing $z$ then increasing $y$):

```
 0.57735026918962576451, -1, -1.5115226281523414610
-1.1547005383792515290,   0, -1.5115226281523414610
 0.57735026918962576451,  1, -1.5115226281523414610

-0.93417235896271569645, -1.6180339887498948482, -0.35682208977308993194
 1.8683447179254313929,   0,                     -0.35682208977308993194
-0.93417235896271569645,  1.6180339887498948482, -0.35682208977308993194

 0.93417235896271569645, -1.6180339887498948482, 0.35682208977308993194
-1.8683447179254313929,   0,                     0.35682208977308993194
 0.93417235896271569645,  1.6180339887498948482, 0.35682208977308993194

-0.57735026918962576451, -1, 1.5115226281523414610
 1.1547005383792515290,   0, 1.5115226281523414610
-0.57735026918962576451,  1, 1.5115226281523414610
```

Afterthought: it could be simplified, as I recognize the values

$$\phi,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3},\dfrac{2}{\sqrt3},\dfrac{\phi}{\sqrt3},\dfrac{2\phi}{\sqrt3},\dfrac{\phi-1}{\sqrt3},\dfrac{\phi+1}{\sqrt3}$$

Comment: I am finding this answer very helpful, thank you.

There is an algebraic step in here I don't understand, though: $\sqrt{\phi^2+(1+2\phi)^2}=\sqrt{6+9\phi}$

Can you elaborate on this simplification?

Comment: @InnisBrendan $\phi^2=\phi+1$ hence $\phi^2+(1+2\phi)^2=\phi+1+1+4\phi^2+4\phi=5\phi+2+4(\phi+1)=6+9\phi$.

Comment: $\phi^2=\phi+1$ This was the step I did not understand. I very much appreciate the help.